# Serving Tensorflow model for production

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, serving

I am using a tensorflow estimator model for multi-label text classification. 
 After having the prediction, I need to serve the model for prediction, but I am not getting the correct path.

```
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'descriptions': np.array(test_descriptions).astype(np.str)},
    test_encoded.astype(np.int32),
    shuffle=False)
##"Code for saving the model"
import pickle
model.save('my_model.h5')
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

##Saving Model part ends

estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
raw_text = ("Pemeriksaan pilihan makanan kita dan makanan yang kita masukkan "
            "ke dalam tubuh kita. Berdasarkan memoar Jonathan Safran Foer.")

predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {'descriptions': np.array([raw_text]).astype(np.str)},
    shuffle=False)

prediction = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)

for movie_genres in prediction:
    top_2 = movie_genres['probabilities'].argsort()[-3:][::-1]

for genre in top_2:
    text_genre = encoder.classes_[genre]
    print(text_genre)
```

I tried tensorflow serving but it didn't work.

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because this example isn't self contained.  What is `test_descriptions`? `test_encoded`?  `"...but it didn't work"`.  How did it not work? Error message(s)?

Comment: After evaluate the model when export the model for serving process it gives up an error  "Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore"